# Importing a list from one visual studio project to another

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, custom-list, list-definition, import

I have sp project (say `project a`) in visual studio that is supposed to deploy the sp solution to my website (say that its running at `http://localhost:xxxx/`).

My goal would be to add the list definition to the above project.

To get the list definition I follow steps mentioned in the following post: [Getting an existing list definition in sharepoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/getting-an-existing-list-definition-in-sharepoint-2010). In short, I create my lists using my web browser, save the site as template (wsp), and import it to another vs solution (project b).

Now `project b` has the definition of the two lists that I want. How to get those definitions into `project a`? Are we supposed to do something like `Add Existing Item...` here? If so what must I import?

Comment: Are you trying to manually copy a list definition from project b to project a, or do it in code?

Comment: Copy the list item from the Visual Studio solution package and change the GUID of the list item and rebuild the package.

Answer (score 1):

Save the site containing the list as a template. Site Settings -> Site Actions -> Save site as template.

In Visual Studio add a new project and select the project type "SharePoint 2013 - Import Solution package".

A wizard will start enabling you to (un)select all needed lists, content types, site columns, etc... After the wizard is done, the selected items will be imported into your Visual Studio project.

Be careful when deploying. If you deploy the solution to the site with the original lists etc you will get conflicts concerning duplicate ID's.

Comment: FYI importing content types and site columns can be done directly in SharePoint by using the Server Explorer. Create a SharePoint connection, browse to the the content type or site column, right click and select "Import ..."